# Start coroutines when the class is not a MonoBehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation, coroutine

**EDIT:** The answer that solves this problem is indeed in the answer of the post whose duplicate is this one. If you have the same problem as in the title, please refer to the other post.

I made a simple rig that moves stuff over time like this:

```
 Transform from;
 Transform to;
 float overTime;
 IUIAnimationEvent chain;
 public delegate void UIchain();
 public event UIchain NEXT_FUNCTION;
 public MoveAction(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime, IUIAnimationEvent chain)
 {
     this.from = from;
     this.to = to;
     this.overTime = overTime;
     this.chain = chain;
 }
 public void Move()
 {
     MonoBehaviour _lead = new MonoBehaviour();
     if (moveRoutine != null)
     {
         _lead.StopCoroutine(moveRoutine);
     }
     moveRoutine = _Move(from, to, overTime);
     _lead.StartCoroutine(moveRoutine);
 }
 IEnumerator _Move(Transform from, Transform to, float overTime)
 {
     Vector2 original = from.position;
     float timer = 0.0f;
     while (timer < overTime)
     {
         float step = Vector2.Distance(original, to.position) * (Time.deltaTime / overTime);
         from.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(from.position, to.position, step);
         timer += Time.deltaTime;
         yield return null;
     }
     if(NEXT_FUNCTION != null)
     {
         NEXT_FUNCTION();
     }
 }
```

However, to make it work like I wish, I have to *instantiate* them, so they can't be a `MonoBehaviour`. Notice what I did with the `_lead` variable. I made it so I could start `coroutines` like any other. If my class is **NOT** a `MonoBehaviour`, how to start a `coroutine` from it?

Or if that isn't possible, how to *instantiate* classes that **ARE** `MonoBehaviour`? I noticed the _use `AddComponent` instead, but the classes are **not** components. They are used by another component and will not be put on a `GameObject` from the inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Coroutines` must be bound to a `MonoBehaviour`. Or in other words, you will need at least one `MonoBehaviour` to start a `coroutine`. And sadly, you cannot instantiate a `MonoBehaviour`:

```
var mono = new MonoBehaviour(); // will not work
```

There is a workaround that I can think of right now. You write your `coroutine` as usual and then you start it from another class that inherits from `MonoBehaviour`. That is, a function only needs to return `IEnumerator` in order to be started as `Coroutine`.

> If another is started, the already started coroutine is stopped and a
>   new one is called

If you want to do it **inside** a `non-MonoBehaviour` class I'm afraid it will not be possible.

> **Remember**: You will need at least one `MonoBehaviour` to start a `coroutine`.

I will call what you want to achieve: a `Coroutine Management` feature and my understanding is that you want to include that feature inside your `non-MonoBehaviour` class. But thanks to my **`Remember`** quote above you cannot do it right now.

But including it in-side a `.dll` might be possible as a `.dll` can contain many classes. And you can use [Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx) to enforce your rules (the `internal` modifier is my favorite).

If I were you I would treat `Coroutine Management` as a separate problem and would build a `.dll` to handle them separately so that it would not mess up with my game-play business.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Generally that would work but I implemented the `void Move()` for the coroutine explicitely so that _only **one** `Move()` can effect one UI component at a time. If another is started, the already started coroutine is stopped and a new one is called._

Comment: @agiro "If another is started, the already started coroutine is stopped and a new one is called" Please, ask this as a new question.

Comment: @Programmer I already added that, now only one can effect one object, as I wanted, it wasn't a question, I can't start from another class because of it.

Comment: @agiro Ok. Got it. Glad your problem is solved.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it can shed some light on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't start coroutines from a class that is not a `MonoBehaviour` as the method `StartCoroutine()` is part of this *class*. 
Just create a new `GameObject` and then add your class as a `Component` on it

You can instantiate your class that inherit from `MonoBehaviour` (for this example `MyClass`) like this:

```
GameObject baseObject = new GameObject();
baseObject.AddComponent<MyClass>();
```

See [singleton pattern](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) for example

Comment: I plan to compile my functions like `Move()` or `RotateToGiven()` to .dll-s, and have a `script` on each of my `UI elements` that have to be animated and just get that from my main Ui manager and all should be fine. Doable? 
I'm concerned with the .dll part

Comment: You can. I keep trying to explain this. You must **not** drive your scrip from `MonoBehaviour`. You need a reference of it from any GameObject.

Comment: @agiro So the cù-Đức-hiếu's solution should work fine

Comment: @Programmer The question is how to start a coroutine from a class that is not a `MonoBehaviour`. Can you?

Comment: Yes, @Programmer is indeed trying hard, but I'm ignorant atm :) The reason is that I have in mind what I _want_ but the _how_ is another thing.

Comment: @Ludovic Programmer have already answered to many of my questions about this UI anim feature I try to implement. It's about the .dll compilation I think.

Comment: @agiro My reply was to Ludovic not you. To Ludovic, yes you can. You need to pass in a reference of **any** MonoBehaviour in the scene. That reference can then be used to start and stop coroutines. Take a look at the duplicated answer if you don't still get it.

Comment: @Programmer I get it now, i upvoted your answer ;) How can you know so many things, i see you on almost every post ^^

Comment: @Programmer I didn't know that (the start of a coroutine). Good one.

Comment: lol not every post. Some of Unity questions. Happy coding!

Comment: @Programmer So we will meet again :) Happy coding ;)

Comment: @Programmer Your solution was indeed fine and given that this indeed was a duplicate post. The code works now, I can chain my animations the way I please. Kudos!